# cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN - to fetch results

Tags: python, opencv

In a python OpenCV program, I am using a grid to display results. A part of the result is also printed on the console.  I am thinking about using  `cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN` to allow the user to select an image.  The following is the code that returns the results.

```
for (i, (score, resultID)) in enumerate(results):
    # load the result image and display it
    print("[INFO] {result_num}. {result} - {score:.2f}".format(result_num=i + 1, result=resultID,
        score=score))
    result = cv2.imread("{}/{}".format(args["dataset"], resultID))
    montage.addResult(result, text="#{}".format(resultID))
```

The above print statement, prints the results.  For example,

```
[INFO] 1. 120546657.jpg - 0.00
[INFO] 2. 120545527.jpg - 0.82
[INFO] 3. 120546664.jpg - 0.86
[INFO] 4. 120546685.jpg - 1.15
```

The montage looks like this:

[image: Example Picture]

Upon the user clicking the picture on the montage, I want to return the `resultID` printed on the image.

My code so far is as follows:

```
for (i, (score, resultID)) in enumerate(results):
    # load the result image and display it
    print("[INFO] {result_num}. {result} - {score:.2f}".format(result_num=i + 1, result=resultID,
        score=score))
    result = cv2.imread("{}/{}".format(args["dataset"], resultID))
    montage.addResult(result, text="#{}".format(resultID))

cv2.imshow("Results", imutils.resize(montage.montage, height=700))
if cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
    print(resultID)
```

Comment: opencv has a puttext function to print on images. Nit sure whether it exists for python

Comment: @Micka Yes...i use cv2.putText to print the filenames in the montage

Comment: Assume one of resized images, named resized; and n images a row; and pt(x,y) of mouse.; and list of resultID named IDs.  `H,W = resized.shape[:2]; num = (y//H * n + x//w); print(IDs[num])`

Comment: what is your question? "How to fetch mouse input with opencv?" or "how to compute grid position from pixel position?"

Comment: @Micka Each image in the grid example given has a filename that is printed using putText on the image.  I want to retrieve the name if a user clicks on the picture.

Comment: your task consists of two problems: 1. recognize click events. 2. somehow extract the associated image informatiom. Did you already solve one of those subtasks? Do you have problems with both subtasks?

Comment: Have problems with both....I guess, if I could recognize click events...then I would be able to get the associated information.  Currently the cv2.EVENT_LMOUSEDOWN, is not fetching even the x,y coordinates

Comment: not sure about the python version but probably you have to connect a callback function with something like cv2.setMouseCallback. Then this function will be called whenever you move the cursor or click and there you can ask whether the event was a leftclick

Comment: have a look at: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_mouse_handling/py_mouse_handling.html

Comment: @Micka Thank you for all the support....I will read this tutorial.